# Obtener información de datta-atribute con jQuery

Tags: jquery, botón

estoy tratando de obtener información de datta-atribute de un button para luego escribir esos datos en etiquetas HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#articleModal" data-id="102" data-nombre="Poducto 100">Ver</button>
```

Para modificar el tag h4 de este código:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="articleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Nombre del articulo</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="datos_ajax"></div>


          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Este es el código de mi js:

```
$('#articleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
      var button = $(event.relatedTarget)  // Botón que activó el modal
      var nombre = button.data('nombre') // Extraer la información de atributos de datos


      var modal = $(this)
      modal.find('.modal-title').text(nombre)
      $('.alert').hide();//Oculto alert
    })
```

Al momento de presionar el button, el h4 no se modifica sino que sigue con el mismo titulo. No he logrado encontrar el error pero supongo que está en el código js. Agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: Marcos , su código si cambia el valor del  _h4_

Comment: Me había olvidado de referenciar a un archivo javascript <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te comento, he probado el código sin cambiar nada, inclusive con varios botones que abrían la misma modal y a mi si me funciona, la lógica de tu programa es correcta para lo que tu quieres hacer.

Tienes que tener alguna etiqueta ***script*** que estas enlazando mal hacia tu ***HTML*** de la librería ***Bootstrap*** o  ***jQuery.***

¡Un saludo!

Answer (score -1):

¿Quieres sacar lo que está en data-nombre del botón y ponerlo en el h4?

Puedes poner

```
nombre = button.attr("data-nombre");
```

Comment: puedes colocar el codigo para que sea mas facil

Comment: solo cambia esta linea:
var nombre = button.data('nombre') // Extraer la información de atributos de datos

Por esta:
var nombre=button.attr("data-nombre");